# Open R Markdown in viewer pane

Tags: r, browser, parameters, r-markdown, render

I'm rendering an R Markdown with parameters with the rmarkdown package' render function.

```
rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd", params = "ask")
```

It opens my default browser (Chrome) asking for the parameter input. I want it to open not in my default browser, but in the viewer pane. Or, alternatively in a different browser, like IE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the instruction described by @J_F and click the Knit to HTML button. Preview will be displayed in the viewer pane.
https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_integration.html

Answer (score 10):

I think you are using `RStudio`. So go to Tools -> Global Options -> R Markdown.

In the shown dropdown menue you can change to viewer pane.

[image]

Comment: It's true I'm using `RStudio`. Switching this setting to viewer pane doesn't solve the issue. The window still opens in Chrome.

Comment: You should press "Apply" instead of "OK" after the changes.

Answer (score 3):

You can preview your file by using the shortcut shift + ctrl + k on  `rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd", params = "ask")` (or shift + command + k for Mac).

EDIT: This will work if you change output preview to viewer pane in Global Options -> R Markdown do as described by @J_F

EDIT 2: Here is an image of the shortcut working in an .R document:
[image]

Comment: It does work when I knit the .Rmd document. However, when I render the document with `rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd", params = "ask")` (which is what I want), it still opens in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, it will work in an .R document as well. Just click on the code and run shif, ctrl, k

Comment: I have no idea how I manage to complete misread your message, as you mentioned nothing about using an .R file. Anyway, I am not sure what you mean since you do get the document in the viewer panel when you use this shortcut. If you want to open it in another browser you will have to change your PC's default browser .

Answer (score 0):

Download [RStudio Preview version](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/). This version will enable you to preview your R Markdown in the viewer pane.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why you can't see it in your viewer pane is that you didn't choose the Knit to HTML. If you have already chosen the Knit to Pdf that will stay as a default so go to Knit and choose the Knit to HTML while making sure your preview is in Viewer Pane